# What bathtub/shower faucet do I need with CSA

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet, bathtub

I have what I believe to be a (CSA) Canadian Standard Association shower kit from approximately 1995. We are in the US if that matters. My wife wants it replaced, which I generally feel comfortable doing. I am just having a hard time determining what I have and what my options are for replacements. Can anyone offer any assistance? I've attached an imugr album with the only identifiable markings on my current setup.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/15I7U.jpg

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: CSA is not a manufacturer ... https://www.csagroup.org/

Comment: CSA just means that it's listed with CSA - it's probably also listed with things on this side of the border, though markings are often poor or on things that get lost like labels. For full replacement you normally have some pipes, and you either ned a shower kit, or a shower/tub kit, depending on what you have now. If you are only going to change cartridge and trim, THEN you have to figure out what in heck you actually have - or opt to replace the whole thing anyway if you can't sort it out.

Comment: Canadians are very nice, i think you will be allowed to replace it with any brand you like without fear of  consequences. Of coarse you need to get the approval of the executive in charge, Ask her for purchase approval BEFORE  taking action.